# Firefox is displaying wrong font for particular web site

Tags: firefox, fonts

I have two systems running Ubuntu 22.04 with Firefox 124.0.1 64 bits installed via deb (not snap).  One system displays the font (presumably Verdana) on a particular website correctly while the other used to, but now displays the font as monospace (which is ugly).

Is it possibly one system or Firefox has corrupted fonts?  Is there a way to fix this?  I remember when I installed the snap Firefox initially I had this exact problem where the snap Firefox displayed the monospace font for this site.  I have confirmed though that the snap Firefox is not currently installed.

Using Firefox's developer tools I get console messages like..

```
Request for font "Times New Roman" blocked at visibility level 2 (requires 3)
```

I think there is a security setting maybe that I've changed that is causing this.

Comment: If a website prescribes a font that is not installed on the system, the browser substitutes the font by something that is installed. You can find out through the Firefox developer tools which fonts are substituted by what. Possibly the Verdana font is not installed on that system. You may need to install `ttf-mscorefonts-installer`.

Comment: Thanks... I've updated my question with further details gained from your advice.

Comment: Downvoter: please explain the downvote.

Comment: Firefox caching fonts sometimes does the unexpected, and the cached font doesn't quite work. tensorflow.org has a menu dropdown, with the dropdown supposed to be indicated with a down pointing triangle, but the cached font just has "AR" there (which does turn upsidedown when clicked!). Refresh the page with crtl+shift+R and the proper down arrow is picked up.(still a problem ff 124.01)

Answer (score 1):

Some fonts were not being displayed because I had changed a setting in `Privacy & Security`.  I had custom settings under `Enhanced Tracking Protection`.  Blocking `Suspected Fingerprinters` was preventing access to the necessary fonts.  I unchecked that box and the site works as suspected. I found the answer on Mozilla's own website [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1426612).